# Search associate array values for one key in array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, dictionary, associative-array

I have an associate array that looks like this with a variable declared for user input

```
NUMBER=$1

declare -A AD
AD[1]=aaaa
AD[2]=bbbb
AD[3]=cccc
AD[4]=dddd
AD[2]=eeee
AD[2]=ffff
AD[4]=gggg
```

If I want to get a user input number and search through that associative array and display a list of values like like

Let's say if the user entered 2, it should search in that array and return me the output as below:
I'm not sure how to do that with search loop if that's what is required to accomplish this.

```
bbbb
eeee
ffff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you

```
AD[2]=something
```

You override what was previously there. It seems as though you want the entries (or just this entry) to be a list, which is not allowed, but you could fake it with a string

```
AD[2]="bbbb eeee ffff"
```

If you want to return the entry as an array, simply return

```
(${AD[2]})
```

This of course only works if you do not have spaces in your words. If you do, deciding on a splitting token and using `(${AD[2]//;/ })` would work (with `;` as a token). To work with this string based approach, you would have to append your array as follows:

```
AD[2]+=" aaa"
Dd[2]+=" bbb"
AD[2]+=" ccc"
```

That way if you want to print given "2" them words one by one then:

```
for word in ${AD[2]}; do
    echo "$word"
done
```

Again, by not quoting `AD[2]` I allow bash to separate the words by spaces. A safer approach, using an agreed about token might be

```
AD[2]+=";aaa"
AD[2]+=";bbb"
AD[2]+=";ccc"

IFS=";" read -ra arr <<< "${AD[2]}"

for word in "${arr[@]}"; do
    [ -z "$word" ] && continue  # If I always use += to add to the array the first word is empty. Use AD[2]=aaa to avoid this rather than +=.
    echo "$word"
done
```

Comment: Thanks @Kabanus for your response,


Well, I want to distinctively list every repeated value in that list if that matches the criteria. If the associative array does not allow that, I'm fine with a different approach too.

Comment: @RajanVashisht Using an array is fine, you just need to decide how save your words. I gave full examples.